# Confusion with HTTP

Tags: http

I am new to web development and came across the term HTTP. I have done some research and wanted to ensure that I correctly understood the term. So, is it true that HTTP, in simple words, a letter containing information in the language that both client and server can understand. Then, that letter is sent to the server thanks to TCP/IP which serves as a car that takes that letter to the server. Then, after the letter is delivered to the server, the server reads the content of the letter and if it is GET request, the server takes the necessary data and ATTACHES that data to the letter and sends back to the client via again TCP/IP. But if it was POST request then the client ATTACHES the DATA to the letter and sends it to the server so that it saves that data in the database. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a text protocol, where the client (usually a browser) sends a request, which is just a properly formatted text. Then the server sends a response, which is also a properly formatted text. TCP/IP is only used to send bytes, which are interpreted as this text by the browser and the web server.

Both GET and POST methods send text requests and responses. The most significant difference between those two is that with POST method, a request can have a body.
It would look like this:

```
> POST /post HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Content-Length: 19
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2        <- this is request's body, this is how it would look like if a form was submitted. GET method doesn't have this part.
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Mon, 17 Feb 2020 22:24:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 27
<
< {"response":{"text": "OK"}}  <- this is a response's body
```

(`>` means a request, a text sent to the server, `<` means a response, a text sent back to the user. Those characters are not sent, it's just for us now to distinguish between those two)

You may say, that images are sent over HTTP too, but it's not text. This is true, but as we all know, for computers everything is just bytes. It's only how we interpret them that makes a distinction between text and image. This is why you can open an image file in Notepad and you will see ... text. Weirdly formatted and impossible to understand, but still text.